# How to duplicate liferay portlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet

I have a custom portlet that I added to Liferay. I am looking for a way to duplicate the portlet, make some very little changes on it and use it on another community i.e. I want to be able to see the two portlets when I login as super admin and click on the add application link. Does anyone know an easy way of doing this?

Comment: If you already have the source of a custom portlet and know how to package it and deploy it as a .war, creating a second one is a matter of copying the sources, and changing the id or name in a few places in the configuration files.

Comment: Yes I know. The truth is that I am not the one that deployed it as a .war

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define any number of portlets in portlet.xml - so if there's currently only one, you can add another one, implement (through copy/paste, inheritance or delegation, just as you like) the functionality needed. If you take a look at the liferay-specific deployment descriptors also in WEB-INF/, you can provide more information about your modified portlet there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If a portlet needs to be duplicated with only small changes, maybe you can look at **portlet preferences** as well. This way, you can add multiple instances of the same portlet on one or more pages, and configuring their behavior at runtime. No need to duplicate the portlet project or to define multiple portlets in your `portlet.xml`.

For more information about portlet preferences, check the [Portlet API JavaDocs](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletPreferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing this is possible, in that case you need to create a new portlet copying all content from the old one and modify it.